# Why is my version of bsearch not working?

Tags: ruby, recursion, binary-search

I am running `bsearch([1,2,3,4,5,6], 6)`

This is my version of bsearch:

```
def bsearch(arr, target)

    return nil if arr.size == 0

    half = arr.size / 2
    left = arr[0...half]
    right = arr[half...-1]

    case target <=> arr[half]
    when 1
      return half + bsearch(right, target)
    when 0
      return half
    when -1
      return bsearch(left, target)
    end
end
```

This is the error I am being thrown:

```
recursion.rb:224:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
    from recursion.rb:224:in `bsearch'
    from recursion.rb:224:in `bsearch'
    from recursion.rb:249:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This is because you return `nil` value when the value is not in the array. You need to ensure the return value isn't `nil` before adding `half` to it.

Comment: I suppose this is homework or something, but for completeness' sake I want to add that Ruby 2.2 added `Array#bsearch`. Also instead of manually messing around with indexes, I'd do something like `left, right = arr.take(half), arr.drop(half)`.

Answer (score 1):

From ruby [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

> .. run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using
>   ... exclude the end value

Your code is excluding the final array element.

```
left = arr[0...half]
right = arr[half...-1]
```

Change to use range operator with `..` instead of `...`

```
left = arr[0..half]
right = arr[half..-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add some debugging code, it can help you save much time and find the root cause.

```
def bsearch(arr, target)

    return nil if arr.size == 0

    half = arr.size / 2
    puts "half: #{half}"
    left = arr[0...half]
    puts "left:#{left}"
    puts "arr:#{arr}"
    right = arr[half...-1]
    puts "right:#{right}"
    ....
end
```

result:

```
left:[1, 2, 3]
arr:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
half:3
right:[4, 5]
left:[4]
arr:[4, 5]
half:1
right:[]
test.rb:16:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
    from test.rb:16:in `bsearch'
    from test.rb:16:in `bsearch'
    from test.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

then you will find some problems.

1. right:[4, 5] => it should be [4, 5, 6]
2. arr = [4,5];half = 1; => right = arr[1...-1] = []

   so `bsearch(right, target)` will return nil

Your code should be:

```
left = arr[0..half]
right = arr[half..-1]
```